# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Angular-Google-Map API. When I load Google Map frist time it go no error. I have list of markers, when I click on it, gives details like location, address, etc. This details show on one form. When I close form and again click on any markers it gives following error.

I automatically attach .map at end of requesting file. Like **angular-cookies.min.js.map**. So that requested resource is not found gives following errors. Because there is no file with .map extension at end.

**So what reason it add .map extension at every file.**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/static/lib/angularjs/js/angular-cookies.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/static/lib/jquery/js/jquery.min.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/static/lib/angularjs/js/angular.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/jquery.min.map
```

Answer (score 0):

map extension is a way for the browser to "unminify" the minified javascript files, so that on client side, debugging will be easier, without impacting performance. Normally getting this error will not effect anything. Everything will work as expected. But if you don't want to see that ugly errors, you can further explore it from [here;](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14415)